# Displaying php results on current page

Tags: php, jquery, get

I have this coding that allows me show the .txt file contents of whatever file is selected from the drop down.

```
<form name="add" method="post" id="add" action="show.php">
   Choose a file:
      <select name="files" id="files" onchange="this.form.submit()">
          <option value="File1">File1</option>
          <option value="File2">File2</option>
      </select>
</form>
```

with corresponding show.php (yes the purpose was to display only the last three lines of the file):

```
<?php
    $ChosenFile = $_POST['files'];
    $file = $ChosenFile.'.txt';
    $contents = escapeshellarg($file);
    $line = `tail -n 3 $contents`;

    echo nl2br($line);
    echo "<br><br>";
?>
```

Trying to get it to display the results below the select drop down instead of direct to the php itself with this code:

```
<script>
    $('#files').on('change', function(){
        $.get('show.php', function(data);
            $('#result').html(data);
          });
        });
</script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

The php works and displays text contents but I can't get it to display below the drop down. What did I miss?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to bind the `onchange` event inline **and** assign the `change` handler in jQuery, try removing the inline `onchange`

Comment: You are not showing enough HTML context for us to understand where the dropdown is in the page relative to the `<div>` into which you are returning results.  This is also a VERY dangerous script.  One could easily post a different value to your API and get the last few lines of whatever file that they choose, so long as the webserver has read access on it. That is a very bad idea.  You should validate the POST input against the same pre-defined list of options you provide to make sure they match.

Comment: You need to decide first if you are going to use jQuery or not.

Comment: @Mike Brant the html contains the form "add". Inside the form is the drop down first, then directly after it's the <div> then directly after that is the <script>. </form>

Comment: I'm sure you got a typo in your script: after `function(data)` you need to change `;` to `{`, so change `$.get('show.php', function(data); $('#result').html(data); });` to `$.get('show.php', function(data) { $('#result').html(data); });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove `onchanged` attribute form `select` tag

```
Choose a file:
<select name="files" id="files">
  <option value="File1">File1</option>
  <option value="File2">File2</option>
</select>
```

you must send form data to `show.php` file to get correct result back

```
 <script>
  $(function(){
     $('#files').on('change', function(){
         $.ajax({
             url: 'show.php',
             type: 'post',
             data: $('form#add').serialize()
         }).done(function(data) {
             $('#result').html(data);
         });
    });
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: I understand now. I had two things trying to do the same and nothing doing what it needed to. This worked exactly as it should. You have learned me. Thanks! @Farnabaz

Answer (score 0):

As your original html and php uses `POST`, you would need to use `POST` in your ajax script as well.

And you are not sending any data to your script.

So the result should be something like:

```
    $('#files').on('change', function(){
      $.post('show.php', $(this).closest('form').serialize(), function(data);
        $('#result').html(data);
      });
    });
```

As mentioned in the comments, you also only need one event handler.